# Dimensionality of a given linear space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be the linear space of of all real functions continuous on $[a,b]$. If $f \in V$, the transformation of $f$, $g=T(f)$ means that

$g(x)=\int_a^bf(t)\sin(x-t) dt $    for $a \leq x \leq b$

What is the rank of $T$.

This is a question from Calculus Volume 2 by Apostol, (Chapter 2, question 26 on page 35). The answer is given to be 2. Is this because g(x) can be expressed as linear combination of sin(x) and a constant. Here sin(x) and constant real make a two dimensional base. Please help me in working out the dimensionality of given space.

Comment: A function doesn't have a rank. A space doesn't have a rank, it has a dimension. The transformation has a rank, which is equal to the dimension of its image.

Comment: Thank you I will make the required corrections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\sin(x-t) = \sin x \cos t - \sin t \cos x$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
g(x) &= \int_a^b f(t) \sin x \cos t \, dt - \int_a^b f(t) \cos x \sin t \, dt \\ &= \sin x \int_a^b f(t) \cos t \, dt - \cos x \int_a^b f(t) \sin t \, dt.
\end{align*}
$$
So the function $g$ is of the form $g(x) = A\sin x + B\cos x$. The image of the transformation $T$ is thus spanned by the two functions $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. In order to show that the rank is two, it remains to show that these functions are linearly independent. You take it from here.

Comment: How you ensure that A and B assume values such that the basis for the range has more than one element?

Comment: @RafaelDeiga That's the "you take it from here" part.